# List which has Another List

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to know what's wrong in this code.

I have a list of date and the second list contain others values.
I'm trying to put all date in the list "daStock" and others values (line,category,duration) in list "stockss". I have a table in my page jsp. I want every date display with his own values.

```html
<%@page import="model.Stock"%>
<%@page import="model.Operateur"%>
<%@page import="model.Descriptionarret"%>
<%@page import="model.Categoriearret"%>
<%@page import="web.Operation"%>
<%@page import="web.UhtBeans"%>
<%@page import="model.Ligne"%>
<%@page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html >

<head >
        
     
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
          <meta name="author" content="MWH Team 2" />

       <script type="text/javascript" src="fichier/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="fichier/ajax_js.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="fichier/calendrier.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" title="Design" href="fichier/design.css" />    
          <link href="./fichier/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="./fichier/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.11.0/jquery-ui.css">
     
         <title>UHT</title>
         
         <script language="javascript">
            function showList() {

                var select = document.getElementById('liste');

                if(select.value == "l1") {
                    document.getElementById('l1').setAttribute('style','visibility:inline');
                } else if(select.value == "l2") {
                    document.getElementById('l2').setAttribute('style','visibility:inline');
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('l3').setAttribute('style','visibility:inline');
                }
            }

       </script>
       
</head>

<body  >
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function getsupport ( )
{
  
  document.SupportForm.submit() ;
}

</script> 

 <% 
       Operateur p = new Operateur();
       String  info="";
       String  info1="";
       String info2="";
  
       
       if (session.getAttribute("oppp")==null){%>
     <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Veuillez vous identifier');
        window.location.href='Connexion.jsp';
        </SCRIPT>
 <%    } else { 
      p = (Operateur) session.getAttribute("oppp");
       if (p.getIsadmin().equals("false"))
       {
        info = p.getNomoperateur(); 
        info2="Operateur";
        info1="opera";
       }
       else
       {
         
       info = p.getNomoperateur(); 
       info2="Administrateur";
       info1="admin";
       }
 }
    %>
    
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function getsupport ( )
{
  
  document.SupportForm.submit() ;
}

</script> 


    <div  style="padding-bottom:30px; margin-top:-10px; background-color: green; background-image: url('./fichier/occpp.png'); 
   
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
       

   "  >
   <div> <label  style="margin-left:1150px; margin-top:30px; margin-right: 2px; color:#ffffff; font-family: Calibri, sans-serif; "><%=info %><br/><%=info2 %></label></div>

        <p   style="color:#ffffff; font-size:36px;  font-family: Coolvetica Rg;"  align="center">Cute Process UHT</p>
   </div>
<div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
<div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas" style="margin-top:18px; ">
<form name="SupportForm" method="post" action="controle">
                         <input type="hidden" name="Adminpanel4" />
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                 
                     <li><a href="#">Acceuil</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="Index.jsp">Saisie des Données</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="Resultats.jsp">Resultats</a></li>
                    <li id="Adminpanel" ><a href="Ligne.jsp">Gestion des Lignes</a></li>
                    <li id="Adminpanel1"><a href="Categorie.jsp">Gestion des Categories</a></li>
                    <li id="Adminpanel2"><a href="Arret.jsp">Gestion des Arrêts</a></li>
                    <li id="Adminpanel3"><a href="Operateur.jsp">Gestion des Operateurs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:getsupport()">Deconnexion</a></li>
        
                     
                </ul>
</form>
        </div>
<button class="sidebar-trigger" data-toggle="offcanvas" style="margin-top:18px;"></button>
        <div id="main">

            

            <div class=" container-fluid body-content "  style="margin-top:10px; ">

 <%
 UhtBeans uhtBs;
 Operation opp = new Operation();
 uhtBs = new UhtBeans();
 uhtBs.setListeLi(opp.allLigne());
 uhtBs.setListeCat(opp.allCategorie());
 uhtBs.setListeArr(opp.allArret());
 %>
 

  <input type="hidden"  name="isSent" id="InputisSent" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="oop" value="<%=info1 %>" /></td>
   
   <br /><br />
   <center>

 <h2 align="center" class="button green center" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Gestion1" >List</h2>
  <br><br>
 
  
 <center id="Gestion1" class="collapse">
  
  <div id="affichage"  style="overflow:auto;">
          <script type="text/javascript">
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
</script>

<div id="export" ><input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable2', 'W3C Example Table')" value="     Export to Excel   ">
</div>
<p></p>
  <center>
  
  <table border="1" id="testTable2" border="1" width=100% class="table table-hover">
 <thead>
 <tr align="center" >
  <th width="50%">Postes</th>
  <th>Poste1 (22h-06h)</th>
  <th>Poste2 (06h-14h)</th>
  <th>Poste3 (14h-22h)</th>
  <th>Total Journé</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 
 <%
 UhtBeans ub = new UhtBeans();
 UhtBeans ub1 = new UhtBeans();
 ub.setListDateSt(opp.allDateStock());
 ub1.setListSt(opp.allStock());
 request.setAttribute("DateStock", ub);
 request.setAttribute("stock", ub1);
 
UhtBeans stockss;
UhtBeans daStock;
daStock = (UhtBeans) request.getAttribute("DateStock");
if(request.getAttribute("stock") != null){
 stockss =(UhtBeans) request.getAttribute("stock");
 
}else {
 Operation opers = new Operation();
 stockss = new UhtBeans();
 stockss.setListSt(opers.allStock());
}

%>
   <%
   Iterator<Stock> listDat = daStock.getListDateSt().iterator();
   while(listDat.hasNext()){
          Stock sd =listDat.next();
    Iterator<Stock> lists = stockss.getListSt().iterator();
    while(lists.hasNext()){
           Stock s =lists.next();
            
   %>
 <tr>
  <th bgcolor="green" class="Date"><%=s.getDate() %></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="cyan">
  <th>DIAGRAMME TEMPS</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
  <th>Durée(min)</th>
 </tr>
 <tbody id="colonne">
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps Calendrier</th>
  <%int d=480; %>
  <th id="d" class="Duree"><%=d %></th>
  <th ></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Temps non disponible</th>
  <th class="Duree" id="d11"><%
    System.out.println("ID DU CATEGORIE EST : "+s.getCategorie());
  
  if (s.getCategorie().equals("0")){
   
  %>
  <%=s.getDuree() %>
   
   <%} %>
  </th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  
 </tr>
 
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps Disponible</th>
  <%int d2; 
  d2=d; %>
  <th><%=d2 %></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Temps disponible non utilisé</th>
  <th  class="Duree">
  <%System.out.println("ID De TDNU EST : "+ s.getCategorie());
  if(s.getCategorie().equals("1")){
   %><%=s.getDuree()%>
   <%} %>
  </th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps d'ouverture</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Préventif et révision équipement</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Autres arrêts planifiés non OP</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps operationnel</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Nettoyage</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Autres arrêts OP planifiés</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps de production</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Arrêts organisationnels</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Arrêts techniques</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="right">
  <th bgcolor="red">Arrêts  technologiques</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Running time</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center">
  <th bgcolor="yellow">Temps net de production</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
 </tr>
 <%
          }}
    %>
 </tbody>
 
 <tr><th colspan="5"><br></th></tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="cyan">
 <th>INDICATEURS DU CUTE</th>
 <th colspan="4">Valeur</th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Efficacité de production (PE)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Efficacité operationnelle (OE)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Efficacité énèrgetique (EE)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Maintenance planifiée (PM)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Nettoyage planifié (CIP)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Arrêts techniques (th)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Arrêts technologiques (TOD)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr align="center" bgcolor="green">
 <th>Utilisation operationnelle (OU)</th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 <th></th>
 </tr>
 <tr>

</table>
   </center>
          
        </div> 
 </center>
  
   
 


      <script>
      $('#InputOperateurMail').on("click", function () {
          // $('#CC').val($(this).val());
               
            $('#CC').val($('#CC').val()+";"+$(this).val());

               
              });
          
          $( "#InputDate" ).datepicker({
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true
            });           
   
      //Le script Ajaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaax
        $(document).ready(function() {  
       
         if ( $("#oop").val()!="admin")
         {
           $("#Adminpanel").hide();
           $("#Adminpanel1").hide();
         $("#Adminpanel2").hide();
           $("#Adminpanel3").hide();
           $("#export").hide();
        
         }
         
         var selectionCount = 1;

             $('#Ajouter').on("click", function () {
              

                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "controle?action=Ajouter",
                     data: {
                      
                      Date: $("#InputDate").val(),
                      NomCat: $("#InputNomCat").val(),
                      Arret: $("#InputArrets option:selected").val(),
                      Ligne: $("#InputLigne").val(),                      
                         Duree: $("#InputDuree").val(),

                     },
                     success: function (result) {
                         $("#affichage").html(result);
                     }
                 });
             });
             
             
    
            
             //Modifier
             $('#Modifier').on("click", function () {


                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "controle?action=Modifier",
                     data: {
                      Date: $("#InputDate").val(),
                      NomCat: $("#InputNomCat").val(),
                      Arret: $("#InputArrets").val(),
                      Ligne: $("#InputLigne").val(),                      
                         Duree: $("#InputDuree").val(),
                      

                     },
                     success: function (result) {
                         $("#affichage").html(result);
                     }
                 });
             });
             //Supprimer
             $('#Supprimer').on("click", function () {


                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "controle?action=Supprimer",
                     data: {
                      Date: $("#InputDate").val(),
                      NomCat: $("#InputNomCat").val(),
                      Arret: $("#InputArrets").val(),
                      Ligne: $("#InputLigne").val(),                      
                         Duree: $("#InputDuree").val(),
                      

                     },
                     success: function (result) {
                         $("#affichage").html(result);
                     }
                 });
             });
             //Recherche 
             $('#Rechercher').on("click", function () {
              
              $("#Retourner").attr('type', 'submit');
              $("#Rechercher").attr('type', 'hidden');

                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "controle?action=Rechercher",
                     data: {
                      Date: $("#InputDate").val(),
                  
                        },
                     success: function (result) {
                         $("#affichage").html(result);
                     }
                 });
             });
             
             //retourner Affichage
     $('#Retourner').on("click", function () {
      $("#Retourner").attr('type', 'hidden');
               $("#Rechercher").attr('type', 'submit');
                 
                      $.ajax({
                          type: "GET",
                          url: "controle?action=Retourner",
                         
                          success: function (result) {
                              $("#affichage").html(result);
                          }
                      });
                  });

                   //Vider les Inputs
              $('#Vider').on("click", function () {


                   $("#InputDate").val("");
                      $("#InputNomCat").val("");
                      $("#InputArrets").val("");
                      $("#InputLigne").val("");
                      $("#InputDuree").val("");                     
              });
             
             //Affichage des valeurs dans les Inputs 
             
     
                    
             $('#affichage').on("click", 'tbody tr', function () {
                 if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                 
                     selectionCount++;
                     selectionCount = 1;
                 }

                 if (selectionCount == 1) {
                  
                  
                     $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
                     
                     $(this).addClass("selected");     
                     
                     var Date = $('.selected').find(".Date").text().trim();
                     var NomCat = $('.selected').find(".NomCat").text().trim();
                     var Arret = $('.selected').find(".Arret").text().trim();
                     var Ligne = $('.selected').find(".Ligne").text().trim();
                     var Duree = $('.selected').find(".Duree").text().trim();
                     
                     //changement du couleur
                     $('#colonne tr').css('background','white');

                     
                     $("#InputDate").val(Date) ; 
                     $("#InputNomCat").val(NomCat);
                     $("#InputArrets").val(Arret);
                     $("#InputLigne").val(Ligne);
                     $("#InputDuree").val(Duree);
                        
                 }
             });
             //Affichage des valeurs dans les Inputs 
             
       
             
             
             
                               var i=1;
                        $( "#espacefournisseur" ).hide();     
                       $( "#espaceF" ).click(function()  {     
                        if(i % 2 == 0)
                   {  $( "#espacefournisseur" ).hide( "slow");
                     i=i+1;
                   }else
                   { $( "#espacefournisseur" ).show( "slow");
                     i=i+1;
                    }});
                     
                       
                });
      
      
      
            </script>

 <!-- Date Pickeeeeeeeer! -->
 
 
    <!-- Tableau obligatoire ! C'est lui qui contiendra le calendrier ! -->
    <table class="ds_box" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="ds_conclass" style="display: none;">
      <tr>
        <td id="ds_calclass"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="fichier/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="fichier/Site.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Error

```html
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Stage-UHT1] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /Resultats.jsp at line 222

219:             <%
220:             Iterator<Stock> listDat = daStock.getListDateSt().iterator();
221:             while(listDat.hasNext()){
222:                 Stock sd =listDat.next();
223:                 Iterator<Stock> lists = stockss.getListSt().iterator();
224:                 while(lists.hasNext()){
225:                     Stock s =lists.next();


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to model.Stock
    at org.apache.jsp.Resultats_jsp._jspService(Resultats_jsp.java:310)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**UhtBeans CLass**

```html
package web;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import model.Categoriearret;
import model.Descriptionarret;
import model.Ligne;
import model.Operateur;
import model.Stock;

public class UhtBeans {
 private Ligne ligne = new Ligne() ;
 private Categoriearret categorie = new Categoriearret();
 private Descriptionarret arret = new Descriptionarret();
 private Stock stock = new Stock();
 private Operateur operateur = new Operateur();
 private boolean login;
 
 private ArrayList<Ligne> listeLi = new ArrayList<Ligne>();
 private ArrayList<Categoriearret> listeCat = new ArrayList<Categoriearret>();
 private ArrayList<Descriptionarret> listeArr = new ArrayList<Descriptionarret>();
 private ArrayList<Stock> listSt = new ArrayList<Stock>();
 private ArrayList<Stock> listDateSt = new ArrayList<Stock>();
 private ArrayList<Operateur> listOp = new ArrayList<Operateur>();
 
public ArrayList<Stock> getListDateSt() {
 return listDateSt;
}
public void setListDateSt(List<Stock> listDateSt) {
 this.listDateSt = (ArrayList<Stock>) listDateSt;
}
 //Operateur
 public Operateur getOperateur() {
 return operateur;
}
public void setOperateur(Operateur operateur) {
 this.operateur = operateur;
}
public ArrayList<Operateur> getListOp() {
 return listOp;
}
public void setListOp(List<Operateur> listOp) {
 this.listOp = (ArrayList<Operateur>) listOp;
}
//Stock
 public Stock getStock() {
 return stock;
}
public void setStock(Stock stock) {
 this.stock = stock;
}
public ArrayList<Stock> getListSt() {
 return listSt;
}
public void setListSt(List<Stock> list) {
 this.listSt = (ArrayList<Stock>) list;
}
//Arrêt
 public Descriptionarret getArret() {
 return arret;
}
public void setArret(Descriptionarret arret) {
 this.arret = arret;
}
public ArrayList<Descriptionarret> getListeArr() {
 return listeArr;
}
public void setListeArr(List<Descriptionarret> listeArr) {
 this.listeArr = (ArrayList<Descriptionarret>)listeArr;
}
//Categories
 public Categoriearret getCategorie() {
 return categorie;
}
public void setCategorie(Categoriearret categorie) {
 this.categorie = categorie;
}
public ArrayList<Categoriearret> getListeCat() {
 return listeCat;
}
public void setListeCat(List<Categoriearret> listCat) {
 this.listeCat = (ArrayList<Categoriearret>)listCat;
}
//Lignes
public Ligne getLigne() {
 return ligne;
}
public void setLigne(Ligne ligne) {
 this.ligne = ligne;
}
public ArrayList<Ligne> getListeLi() {
 return listeLi;
}
public void setListeLi(List<Ligne> listeLi) {
 this.listeLi = (ArrayList<Ligne>)listeLi;
}
public boolean isLogin() {
 return login;
}
public void setLogin(boolean login) {
 this.login = login;
}

}
```

Comment: Whats your problem exactly?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you please let us know what is problem you facing

Comment: I added the error below

Comment: I think youre missing closing brackets for the while statements

Comment: no its closed in the end of the page jsp

Comment: Could you paste your UhtBeans class?

Answer (score 1):

I think `stockss.getListSt()` returns a list of String. So casting an element of the list to a Stock cannot possibly work. And that's what you're trying to do in `Stock s =lists.next();`

Comment: No wonder. You cannot cast a String to a Stock. It could be possible if String inherited from Stock, and I'm pretty positive it isn't the case.

Comment: so there is another way to do it?

Comment: You could try this: `String s =lists.next();`, but I don't know if it makes sense in your application...

Comment: in data base i have a table contain (id,date,ligne,category,arret,duree) thats i want its to display this table in a table in a jsp but the problem is that every date have many value of 'duree' so when im trying to display all value of the same date in one table doesn't work it give a table for every value.I hope you understand

Comment: Essaye en français, ça ira mieux

Comment: j'ai une table dans ma base de données contient les champs suivants:(id,date,ligne,arret,duree) je veux afficher la liste de tout ces element dans un seule tableau c'est a dire chaque date est associée avec ses valeurs.quand j'essaye de faire ca j'ai obtenu plusieurs tableaux par exemple pour la date x la duree de arret1 dans un tableau, la duree de arret2 dans un 2eme tableau et la duree de arret3 dans un 3eme tableau ainsi de suite mai ce que je veux c'est d'afficher tout ces element dans un seule tableau

Comment: Tu parles de tableaux HTML ?

Comment: oui j'essaye de faire l'affichage dans ma page jsp

Comment: Il faut que tu ne mettes qu'une ligne dans ta boucle. Si tu mets toute ta structure `<table> <tr><td>...</td>...</tr>...</table>`dans ta boucle, il va faire un tableau par entrée. Il faut que tes balises `<table>` et `</table>` soient en dehors de ta boucle.

Comment: Cela dit, je ne peux que trop te déconseiller l'usage de de scriptlets, totalement obsolètes dans une JSP moderne. Si tu veux progresser, essaies de plutôt regarder du côté de JSTL et d'Expression Language.

Comment: si les balises sont en dehors de la boucle comment je peux parcourir ma liste(j'ai ajouté la page entière au dessus)